# Getting dmesg in the terminal

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to get `dmesg` logs in `terminal` automatically each time a log comes to `/var/log/messages`

just to avoid typing `dmesg` or `dmesg <args>`

Comment: `/var/log/messages` is not written by the kernel but by the [syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf) daemon.

Comment: @San Are you trying to monitor updates to the `/var/log/messages` explicitly, or are you trying to get kernel messages to display immediately in your console as they occur?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd one. I have got it, Thank you for your response !!

Answer (score 2):

Run [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail)`-f /var/log/messages` in the terminal.